# Creating an embedded playlist inside a Tumblr Post

Tags: audio, tumblr, jwplayer, playlist

Tumblr has an option to upload one audio file as a post but I'm looking to make an embedded playlist of multiple tracks. I'm trying to use JW Player ( http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5 ) to do it but so far no success.

Here is the code I'm inserting into the Head of my tumblr Theme:
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://216.172.180.215/~hello/music/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>`

And here is the code I'm inserting directly into a Tumblr post:
    `<div id="container">Loading the player ...</div> <script type="text/javascript"> jwplayer("container").setup({ flashplayer: "http://216.172.180.215/~hello/music/jwplayer/player.swf", file: "http://216.172.180.215/~hello/music/jwplayer/video.mp4", height: 270, width: 480 }); </script>`

This is how the JW Player Guide explains it should work, but since it's not I'm assuming that the Tumblr source code is doing something to prevent it from working. Any insights as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The code below worked for me:

```html
<div id='container'></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jwplayer('container').setup({
'flashplayer': 'http://216.172.180.215/~hello/music/jwplayer/player.swf', 
'file': 'http://216.172.180.215/~hello/music/jwplayer/video.mp4', 
'height': '270', 
'width': '480' 
});
</script>
```